# Is there any user interface available in yii framework for tabular data input?

Tags: database, datagrid, yii-extensions, yii

Hi friends I want to know if there is some widget available using which I can insert multiple rows data items at same time and update database as I insert them.

Like this form

http://i49.tinypic.com/9s5hg5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. You generally have to roll your own