# Can someone please point me to ztabularinputmanager implementation

Tags: database, yii, yii-extensions, tabular

I need to implement tabular input form in yii (by tabular I mean multiple models at same time)

as I have asked in this question

[Is there any user interface available in yii framework for tabular data input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414185/is-there-any-user-interface-available-in-yii-framework-for-tabular-data-input/13418762#13418762)

But after searching internet I found ztabularinputmanager extension of yii as possible solution.

But I am unable to find any good documentation or implementation detail about this extension.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that multimodelform extension for yii might be a better option since it gives you a sample implementation.  Here is the link to the extension and to the sample implementation http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/multimodelform/

I think this extension is pretty good and easier to implement than ztabularinputmanager.  Also I believe that the creator of the extension is pretty active in Yii's extension forums if you need to ask him something.